# Data is not being inserted and no exception is being thrown in android sqlite

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am trying to insert some data in SQLite database, but data is not being inserted nor any exception is being thrown.
It is possible that I am missing something obvious but I am not able to figure it out.
Here is my code to insert data:

```
    public void addTransactionToDatabase(Transaction transactionClass) {

    String query = "INSERT INTO " + TABLE_TRANSACTION__NAME + " ( " + COLUMN_ACCOUNT_TYPE_NAME + "," + COLUMN_AMOUNT_NAME + ", " +
            COLUMN_CATEGORY_NAME + ", " + COLUMN_TIME_NAME + ", " + COLUMN_DATE_NAME + ", " + COLUMN_TIMESTAMP_NAME + ", " + COLUMN_REASON_NAME + " )" + " VALUES " + "( " +
            "\'" + transactionClass.getAccount() + "\', \'" + transactionClass.getAmount() + "\', \'" + transactionClass.getCategory() + "\', \'" +
            transactionClass.getTime() + "\', \'" + transactionClass.getDate() + "\', DATETIME(\'now\')" + ", " + "\'" + transactionClass.getReason() + "\'" + ");";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, query);
    try {

        db.rawQuery(query, null);

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error while inserting transaction: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    db.close();
}
```

Here is the table creation:

```
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_TRANSACTION__NAME + " ( " + COLUMN_TIMESTAMP_NAME + " TEXT PRIMARY KEY, " +
            COLUMN_REASON_NAME + " TEXT, " + COLUMN_CATEGORY_NAME + " TEXT, " + COLUMN_AMOUNT_NAME + " INTEGER, " +
            COLUMN_ACCOUNT_TYPE_NAME + " TEXT, " + COLUMN_TIME_NAME + " TEXT, " + COLUMN_DATE_NAME + " TEXT, " +
            "FOREIGN KEY (" + COLUMN_ACCOUNT_TYPE_NAME + ") REFERENCES " + TABLE_ACCOUNT_NAME + "(" + COLUMN_ACCOUNT_TYPE_NAME + ") , " +
            "FOREIGN KEY ( " + COLUMN_CATEGORY_NAME + ") REFERENCES " + TABLE_CATEGORY_NAME + "(" + COLUMN_CATEGORY_NAME + ") )");
```

The table is created and a row count comes out to be zero every time I check it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is `db.execSQL(query);` you must call and not `db.rawQuery(query, null);`  
`rawQuery` is used to fetch rows.  
Are you sure about all the `\`?

Comment: The problem got solved when I used execSQL instead of rawQuery. Didn't know the exact difference between rawQuery() and execSQL() methods. It's weird that no exception is being thrown despite the fact that I am using the wrong method to insert data. \ is fine.

Comment: You must use rawQuery with SELECT statements